# How to do static Routing for different networks on Linux?

Tags: networking, routing

I am new to networking.

And I have 3 networks are LANA "10.8.0.0/16" that consists of (pc1a "10.8.0.10/16" and pc2a "10.8.0.11/16") and are connected to RouterAC "10.8.0.1/16".

On the other hand, I have LANB "172.16.8.0/24" which consists of (pc1b "172.16.8.10/24" and pc2b "172.16.8.11/24") and are connected to RouterBC "172.16.8.1/24".

Lastly, LANC "192.168.8.0/24" and consists of (pc1c "192.168.8.10/24" and pc2c "192.168.8.11/24") and a gateway with IP address 192.168.1.8/24 that is connected to LANC too.

RouterAC and RouterBC and the gateway are all connected to LANC.

Now my question is how to connect pc1a with pc1b? and pc2b with pc2a? and pc1a with pc1c?

Comment: just set default route to local router. can you **edit** you question with result of `ip route show` on all pc1x (that is pc1a, pc1b, pc1c)

Comment: @Archemar this is not going to work in LANC, because you need different routes into LANA and LANB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RouterAC is the gateway for LANA, and RouterBC is the gateway for LANB, you don't have to worry about routing in LANA and LANB.

You also already have routes on RouterAC into LANA and LANC, and on RouterBC into LANB and LANC, so you don't need to configure those. You just need to make sure that forwarding is enabled, and if you use home-routers, they don't do funny things like NAT.

However, LANC is more tricky. The simplest way probably is to set static routes for LANA and LANB on the gateway (I am going to call this box "ISP-gateway", assuming that's what it is from now on), if you can.

If you cannot, the next simplest method is to find some other gateway (default route) for LANC, where you can set up static routes. Depending on your actual hardware, you can (1) re-use RouterAC or RouterBC, (2) get a new router, (3) use some other box already on LANC. Only you can make this choice, unless you tell us more details.

Then you also need to set up a default route to the "ISP-gateway" on the new gateway for LANC.